# Combine multiple jar into one (using maven)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-2, maven-3, javafx-8

I have a project in javafx , I have 3 dependencies I try to combine them with my principale jar using maven : 
The result I got a jar (1.82mb) but when I click he dosen't launch noting appears.

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scilab.forge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlatexmath</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>fxgraphics2d</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.6_20</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>FXCalc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

and this is some screenshot :

[image]
[image]

The problem : the jar file I got dosen't work , it dosen't want to launch , I tried using ant and gradle but I don't know how to use them.

**EDIT :** After trying the solution I get a jar but it still dosen't launch and I have no error.
[image]
**EDIT 2 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>fxgraphics2d</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scilab.forge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlatexmath</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>CalculatorFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

Comment: how are you combining them?

Comment: I used "add framework support" then I modified the pom.xml file by add the dependencies (3 in my case) then I build an artifacts I got a jar that dosen't want to launch.

Comment: you need to use [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create single jar with dependencies in maven.

Comment: @Adi I downloaded maven but I didn't try compile or something because I don't know what to use , is it obligatory to download this plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following plugin to your `pom.xml` after dependencies:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>sampler.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then run the `mvn package` command from your base directory, where your project is. This will generate a single jar in the target folder.

Comment: yes I get a jar file but it dosen't work I don't know why. (look the picture I added in the question)

Comment: @HinoHara - please see edited answer on how to configure main class. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but I still have the same problem , I will copy pom.xml for you to check it. thanks @Adi

Comment: I just double click on the jar but noting is displayed. @Adi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60407/discussion-between-adi-and-hinohara).

Comment: In my case I needed a single jar to execute from linux cron, no several jars , folders, etc. Your snippet works for me. Thank you!