# How should I import PowSyBl into Anylogic and using its libraries to do powerflow calculations?

Tags: java, maven, jar, external, anylogic

I want to model and simulate the electricity grid, however, there is not any Anylogic library that help me with this purpose and the powerflow calculations. I have searched for java packages that may help, and I could find PowSyBl at:

"https://www.powsybl.org/index.html".

However, I have no clue how to import and use this package:

https://www.powsybl.org/pages/download/

or any of its Java libraries:

https://www.powsybl.org/pages/documentation/developer/repositories/

to Anylogic after downloading from GitHub. There is no "Jar" file there, and there is no Java classes inside the zip file to call within Anylogic. There is a tutorial page that guide how to write Java code to do powerflow calculations, but I cannot run or configure the package to be able to follow its instructions:

https://www.powsybl.org/pages/documentation/developer/tutorials/loadflow.html

How should I prepare this Java package to be used with Anylogic? Is there any way to do that at all?

Comment: Hi Sharif, welcome to SOF. "Can you guide me" is, unfortunately, not a great SOF question, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . However, it sounds like you need to compile the code they provide into a jar file yourself. You can do this yourself with any Java IDE, google that to get started.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Indeed a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with a solution myself and I'd like to share that with the community.
You have to build the JAR packages yourself using Maven, Gradle, etc. [This](https://github.com/powsybl/powsybl-starter/) is where you can find the dependency to include in a Maven project. Use [this](https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/template-how-to-write-a-tips-blog-post) guide to build it. However, the default built packages include 141 JAR files, which is not handy to be used in Anylogic, in my case. Thus, I customized the default build a little bit to assemble the JAR files into one JAR file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591991/combine-multiple-jar-into-one-using-maven) is where you can find the Maven plug-in to do that.